# Extract *.jar from *.aar and import; Failed resolution of: Lcom/xxx/xxx/xxx/R$layout when APK running

Tags: android, android-layout, ant, aar, android-multidex

ALL.
My project base on android NDK.
It use javac, aapt and d8 to compile APK with build.xml.
Don't use Android Studio and build.gradle.

I want to use some third party sdk. All sdk is *.aar files.

I decompress *.aar to *.jar; and import *.jar, res,assert and all files to our project.
Some *.jar can work normal, but some can't.

It have follow error.
**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/thirdsdk/thirdsdkui/R$layout;**

From above information,
It seem that the third sdk class use R.layout itself com.thirdsdk.thirdsdkui.R.layout when apk running,
not my project package class name  R.layout.

Some document tell me, if want it work when use *.jar.

So the third sdk need use follow code:
int layoutId = getResources().getIdentifier("thirdsdk_layout_name", "layout", getPackageName());
setContentView(layoutId);

if follow this, so it error.
setContentView(R.layout.thirdsdk_layout_name);

Who have any suggestion for me to resolve it.

Thanks!

1、I try to find a method to import *aar file wuth ant build.xml. But can't find it.

2、I check dx or d8 multidex, i think it work normally.

3、I try to add R.class; R$layout.class for com.thirdsdk.thirdsdkui and repackaging a jar, it error when D8  compile step. It show only one R.class in project.

Comment: Why do you manually extract the JAr file from aar instead of directly using the aar as it is supposed to? Also you shouldn't use the old ant based build process from Eclipse anymore. Migrate to Android Studio and gradle based build process.

Comment: Thanks, It seem a good idea.  I want to resolve it quickly now.Just only meet this one problem. If migrate to Android Studio, I think it should spend so long time to debug it.

Comment: .aar archives were introduced AFAIR long after the switch to Android Studio/gradle build system. I don't think including into an old-style project will get easier than migrating to AS. I know the Android Studio had an migration system to import an Eclipse project. Not sure if recent versions still have it. But the old versions should still be available. Just check one of the tutorials online hot to migrate an Eclipse project to Android Studio.

Comment: I don't have complete Eclipse project, Only use NDK, JDK tools and build.xml to build project. I want the project can compile for windows, android, iOS easliy.